# Passed a List thru ViewBag but can't do LINQ Select on it from MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass a 2nd List of objects from the Controller to the
View via the ViewBag

Here is the line from my controller code.

```
ViewBag.FeaturedProductList = await Service.SendAsync(new ProductQuery());
```

The return object is the following

```
public class FeaturedProductListDto : IDto
{
    public IEnumerable<FeaturedProductDto> Contents { get; set; }
}
```

In the View, I need to do a linq to select from the
ViewBag.ViewBag.FeaturedProductList in the following line.

```
@foreach (var productGroup in  ViewBag.FeaturedProductList.Select((e,
i) => new {Product = e, Grouping = (i/3)}).GroupBy(e => e.Grouping))
                {
                }
```

I need to group the number of items from the list in sets of 3 but the
Select is throwing an error as the following

Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically
dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or
expression tree type.

I used the same code for my other List which I passed in as the Model
and it works.

This line works. @foreach (var productGroup in Model.Select((e, i) =>
new { Product = e, Grouping = (i / 4) }).GroupBy(e => e.Grouping))

Do I need to recast the ViewBag.FeaturedProductList? What is the fix
for this? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ViewBag is a dynamic dictionary. Items in this dictionary are of type `dynamic`. You cannot use LINQ methods on that.

You need to cast  `ViewBag.FeaturedProductList` to `FeaturedProductListDto` type and use the Contents property which is a collection type on which we can apply LINQ extension methods.

```
@foreach (var item in  ((FeaturedProductListDto) ViewBag.FeaturedProductList).Contents 
                                  .Select(//your existing select code goes here))
{

}
```

I am not quite sure what you are trying to do with the `GroupBy` inside your `Select`. My personal preference is doing all such things in the action method/another layer which provides data to the action method and keep the razor markup with minimal C# code, and with more HTML markup for the page. :)